# send html email using php deliver message as html code

Tags: php, email, html-email

iam sending html message contains table

when i recive message on gmail,hotmail,yahoo account it works fine but when receiving on other client 
ie Microsoft outlook it resolve it as html code !!

here is my email headers

```
            'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
    'Content-Type: text/html;charset= UTF-8' . "\r\n" .
            'From: me <me@client.com>'
```

Comment: Have you checked that the client is displaying as HTML and not as Plain Text?

Comment: Checked , and i can't find any option to this plus this is message header in inbox Content-Type: text/html;charset= UTF-8

From: premieregypt.com <no-reply@premieregypt.com>

Reply-To: me <me@client.com>
Message-Id: <20120516101902.2C49822C4D@ns395384.ovh.net>
Date: Wed, 16 May 2012 12:19:02 +0200 (CEST)

Comment: Have you had other HTML based emails displaying correctly in Outlook?

Comment: @chief17 Yes i had html message very good on google mail , but @ outlook or godady mail redaer no luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I Always use this function ,and it helps

```
  function sendHTMLemail($HTML,$from,$to,$subject,$fromname)
        {
            $headers = "From: ".$fromname." <".$from.">\r\n";
            $headers.= "Reply-To: ".$fromname." <".$from.">\r\n";
            $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 

            $boundary = uniqid("HTMLEMAIL"); 

        // First we be nice and send a non-html version of our email        
            $headers .= "Content-Type: multipart/alternative;".
                        "boundary = $boundary\r\n\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "This is a MIME encoded message.\r\n\r\n"; 
            $headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
                        "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";                    
            $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode(strip_tags($HTML))); 
            // Now we attach the HTML version
            $headers .= "--$boundary\r\n".
                        "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n".
                        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n\r\n";                    
            $headers .= chunk_split(base64_encode($HTML)); 
            // And then send the email ....
            mail($to,$subject,"",$headers);

        }
```

Comment: i used this function put faield this example of msg --HTMLEMAIL4fb3a5e273c28

Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1

Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64



CgoJCgkJCgkKCQoJCQoKCQkJCgkJCQoJCQkJCgkJCQoKCQkJCgkJCQoJCQkJCgkJCQkJCgkJCQkJ

CU5hbWUgOiBTYW15Q29tcGFueSBOYW1lOiBzYW15RW1haWwgOnNhbXltYXNzb3VkQGdtYWlsLmNv

bVRlbGVwaG9uZSA6MDEwMDMzMzMzMUZheDogQ291bnRyeTogRUdZUFRUb3BpYzogUGF5cm9sbCBz

ZXJ2aWNlc01lc3NhZ2UgOkhlbGxvCQkJCQkKCQkJCQoJCQkKCgkJCQoJCQkKCQkJCQoJCQkJCXd3

dy5wcmVtaWVyZWd5cHQuY29tIAoJCQkJCUNsaWNrIGhlcmUgdG8gdW5zdWJzY3JpYmUgZnJvbSB0

aGlzIGVtYWlsIG5vdGlmaWVyCgkJCQkKCQkJCgoJCQ

Answer (score 0):

I know this isn't an answer for your question, but I suggest using a mailing library, that will allow you to send mails much more easily, and supports features such as attachments, authentication, etc.
I recommend [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org) which works great, is simple and well documented.